# Change value of an item in a collection in a dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, collections

I'm trying to create a dictionary which has a collection for every key. The reason for this is that I want to retrieve several values from the same key later on. In this example I want to have the total value (val) of a unique key as well as the number of occurrences (n):

```
sub update()
Dim dict As Dictionary
Dim coll As Collection
Set dict = New Dictionary
Set coll = New Collection

coll.Add 100, "val"
coll.Add 3, "n"
dict.Add "coll", coll

Debug.Print dict.item("coll")("val")
Debug.Print dict.item("coll")("n")
```

This works fine so far, the problem occurs when I try to update the value in the collection (object doesn't support this):

```
dict.item("coll")("val") = dict.item("coll")("val") + 100
```

What I tried:

> If I use an array instead of the collection, there is no error but the value doesn't change.
>   It only works if I read out the collection to variables, change the value, create a new collection, remove the old from the dictionary and add the new collection.

Is there any way to do it like my approach above in a single line? 
I would also be happy for an alternative solution to the task.

Comment: For similar problems, I have utilized a User Defined Object (Class) and then added the class object to a collection.  (The UDO can have multiple properties; and can even have a collection as one of its properties).  The key is some unique string.   You can probably do something similar with the Dictionary object, as with the Collection, but I've not worked with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately im not yet really into UDO, have to have a closer look at it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you added an item to the collection, you cannot change it that easily. Such expression:

```
coll("n") = 5
```

will cause ***Run-time error '424': Object required***.

You can check it by yourself on the simple example below:

```
Sub testCol()
    Dim col As New VBA.Collection
    Call col.Add(1, "a")

    col("a") = 2  '<-- this line will cause Run-time error '424'

End Sub
```

---

The only way to change the value assigned to the specified key in the given collection is by removing this value and adding another value with the same key.

Below is the simple example how to change the value assigned to a collection with key [*a*] from 1 to 2:

```
Sub testCol()
    Dim col As New VBA.Collection
    With col
        Call .Add(1, "a")
        Call .Remove("a")
        Call .Add(2, "a")
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Below is your code modified in order to allow you to change the value assigned to the given key in the collection:

```
Sub update()
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim coll As Collection
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    Set coll = New Collection

    coll.Add 100, "val"
    coll.Add 3, "n"
    dict.Add "coll", coll

    Debug.Print dict.Item("coll")("val")
    Debug.Print dict.Item("coll")("n")
    'This works fine so far, the problem occurs when I try to update the value in the collection (object doesn't support this):

    Dim newValue As Variant
    With dict.Item("coll")
        newValue = .Item("val") + 100
        On Error Resume Next '<---- [On Error Resume Next] to avoid error if there is no such key in this collection yet.
        Call .Remove("val")
        On Error GoTo 0
        Call .Add(newValue, "val")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was a very clear explanation. For now Im doing the update in a seperate function which makes the main code more readable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not elegant perhaps, but maybe you can write a sub to update a collection by a key:

```
Sub UpdateCol(ByRef C As Collection, k As Variant, v As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
    C.Remove k
    On Error GoTo 0
    C.Add v, k
End Sub
```

Used like this:

```
Sub Update()
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim coll As Collection
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    Set coll = New Collection

    coll.Add 100, "val"
    coll.Add 3, "n"
    dict.Add "coll", coll

    Debug.Print dict.Item("coll")("val")
    Debug.Print dict.Item("coll")("n")

    UpdateCol dict.Item("coll"), "val", dict.Item("coll")("val") + 100
    Debug.Print dict.Item("coll")("val")
End Sub
```

With output as expected:

```
100 
3 
200
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a User Defined Object (Class).  Hoepfully you can adapt this to your problem.

Rename the Class Module `cMyStuff` or something else meaningful.

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
Private pTotalVal As Long
Private pCounter As Long

Public Property Get TotalVal() As Long
    TotalVal = pTotalVal
End Property
Public Property Let TotalVal(Value As Long)
    pTotalVal = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Counter() As Long
    Counter = pCounter
End Property
Public Property Let Counter(Value As Long)
    pCounter = Value
End Property
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update()
    Dim cMS As cMyStuff, dMS As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long

Set dMS = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To 3
    Set cMS = New cMyStuff
    With cMS
        .Counter = 1
        .TotalVal = I * 10
        If Not dMS.Exists("coll") Then
            dMS.Add "coll", cMS
        Else
            With dMS("coll")
                .TotalVal = .TotalVal + cMS.TotalVal
                .Counter = .Counter + 1
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next I

With dMS("coll")
    Debug.Print "Total Value", .TotalVal
    Debug.Print "Counter", .Counter
End With

End Sub
```

*Results in Immediate Window*

```
Total Value    60 
Counter        3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! same as above.. I have to get into UDO first, never used a Class Module so far. Looks like there are many possibilities.